# How can I get the input from html to .ts?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm an ionic beginner, I'm trying to push user input to Firebase,

in my html file:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>E-mail </ion-label>
      <ion-input type="email" value="" placeholder="Type your e-mail"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

I have the inputtext field, but I handle firebase operations in my ts file, how can I send this input value to my ts file so I can push it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the component class file (what you call ts file), you can add a class member, let's call it `email`:

```
@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent {
 private email: string;
}
```

And you can bind it in your template with `ngModel`:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>E-mail </ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="email" type="email" value="" placeholder="Type your e-mail"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```